# How to change item in a list with sml?

Tags: sml, ml

I have a list of tuples, I want to have a function which randomly choose two tuples in this list and then swap this two tuples.

for example, if I have a list as ((0 , 0), (1 , 0), (1 , 1), (1 , 2) ,(2 , 2), (0 , 2)), then, randomly choose two tuples. if (0,0) and (1,0) are chosen, then the return result of this function will be ((1 , 0), (0 , 0), (1 , 1), (1 , 2) ,(2 , 2), (0 , 2)).

I am new to SML, I am struggling in it. there is a psudo-code, I suppose it is not right, anyone can help me with the right one? :

```
  fun permutation(lst:(int*int) list)=
  let
    val nextInt = Random.randRange (1,List.length(lst))
    val r = Random.rand (1,1)
    val x1 = nextInt r
    val x2 = nextInt r
    val temp = sub(lst,r1)
    update(lst,r1,sub(lst,r2))
    update(lst,r2,temp)
  in
    lst
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Something simple you can do is make a helper function that takes two indices and a list, and returns the two tuples at those indices.  Something like

```
fun get_two (i1, i2, xs) =
  let
    fun aux (_, _, [], _, val1, val2) = (val1, val2)
      | aux (i1, i2, x::xs, current_index, val1, val2) =
          if i1 = current_index
          then aux (i1, i2, xs, current_index + 1, SOME x, val2)
          else if i2 = current_index
          then aux (i1, i2, xs, current_index + 1, val1, SOME x)
          else aux (i1, i2, xs, current_index + 1, val1, val2)
  in
    aux (i1, i2, xs, 0, NONE, NONE)
  end
```

Then write another function that takes in a list, uses this get_two helper function to find two values and their positions in the list, and produces a new list that is the same as the input list, except with these two values switched.